# Set setting of embeded device via http like TP-LINK router

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on embedded device, the main purpose of the device is to collect data and send them to server.

The device can connect via GPRS modem or LAN, also the device contains rs232 port.

I want to create UI to set configuration of the device, like server ip, connect via LAN or GPRS.... example: some TP-LINK routers can be configure via HTTP protocol(10.0.0.138), did there is any way to do that?

I use uIP(micro ip), also Telit modem.

Comment: The target platform, its OS (if any), its available memory resources, and whether it has a file system would be useful information to enable this question to be answered (and probably prevent it being closed and/or down-voted).  Edit the question rather than responding in comments, otherwise you won't save it.  Other information about Telit, GPRS, LAN and RS232 is largely irrelevant - any solution will work through and channel that your TCP/IP stack already works on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routers do that by embedding a webserver, usually running on embedded Linux because the server and router software is readily available as open-source code.

Whether your target can support a web server will depend on its available resources.  Web servers designed for Linux may be hard to port to a system with no POSIX OS or filesystem and very little memory, on the other hand it is possible to implement a minimal HTTP server very tiny platforms as described in [this article](http://www.embedded.com/design/connectivity/4023312/2/Miniature-Web-Server).

uIP includes an HTTP server already, but I think only for serving static web pages.  [lwIP](http://www.nongnu.org/lwip/) may be a better starting point; it is better supported and appears to have a greater number of web/HTTP server examples and contributed code.